# Why does android studio allow me to compile with syntax errors

Tags: android, build, android-studio, syntax-error

Hi this may sound like a weird question, but I am new to Android Studio. So far I really like it, but there is one thing that is bugging me. In Eclipse if I ever had a syntax error in my code for example I forgot a ; or something like that. It would not allow me to build my project until I fixed the error.

In android studio I removed some buttons that are referenced several times in the code, and I expected it to gong it and tell me all the places that I referenced the button, but it just runs like normal. Then whenever I get to the part in code where those buttons are referenced the app just crashes.

Is there a way to get Android Studio to find syntax errors?

Comment: There's a price to pay for using unstable IDEs...

Comment: Is it possible that you are in File->Power Safe Mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse uses a specially instrumented compiler to find errors.  The compiler that is compiling your code is the the thing that is generating error messages you see in the IDE

Studio (and Netbeans, incidentally) don't work like that.  Your app is assembled by an external build system (Gradle, in the case of Studio), using whatever tools it finds.  Studio, independently, generates error messages by analyzing artifacts.

Every now and then, Studio gets out of sync.  **A rebuild will usually fix it.**